# i can't use the method of UIButton that i write

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want write a method for button so i can set the image and title with one line of code, but it can't be used.

```
+(id)init {
    UIView *myLeftView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/3,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    myLeftView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:26/256.f green:31/256.f blue:36/256.f alpha:0.7];
    UIButton *accessButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, myLeftView.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    [self setUpButton:accessButton withImage:@"Menu_Avatar" title:@"access"];
}

-(void)setUpButton:(UIButton *)button withImage:(NSString *)imageName title:(NSString *)title {
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.myLeftView addSubview:button];
}
```

this above is the method i write in UIView class.

Comment: You have a class method (the `+` in the `+(id)init`) and your try inside it to use `self` for an instance method (the `-` in the `-(void)...`). Also, the `init` isn't clear of what it does and doesn't respect the various init method nomenclature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the that, you can not call `self` from a class function.

If you look at the `init` function declaration, it is with `+`, which means it is a class function.

You can do two things:

Keep the `init` function as a class function, and change the function below into a class function two.

```
+(id)init {
    UIView *myLeftView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/3,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    myLeftView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:26/256.f green:31/256.f blue:36/256.f alpha:0.7];
    UIButton *accessButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, myLeftView.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    [NAMEOFTHECLASS setUpButton:accessButton withImage:@"Menu_Avatar" title:@"access"];
}

+(void)setUpButton:(UIButton *)button withImage:(NSString *)imageName title:(NSString *)title {
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.myLeftView addSubview:button];
}
```

change `NAMEOFTHECLASS` into the name of the class.

The other thing is to change the `init` function to instance function. Do the following:

```
-(id)init {
    UIView *myLeftView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/3,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    myLeftView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:26/256.f green:31/256.f blue:36/256.f alpha:0.7];
    UIButton *accessButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, myLeftView.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    [self setUpButton:accessButton withImage:@"Menu_Avatar" title:@"access"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this :

```
-(instancetype)init{
    if (self == [super init]) {
       UIView *myLeftView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/3,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    myLeftView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:26/256.f green:31/256.f blue:36/256.f alpha:0.7];
    UIButton *accessButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, myLeftView.bounds.size.width, 44)];
//    [accessButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_Avatar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//    [accessButton setTitle:@"access" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setUpButton:accessButton withImage:@"Menu_Avatar" title:@"access"]; 
    }
return self ;
}
```